# search api query operator IN

Tags: search

I want to search mix values inside $filter->condition e.g

$mix =  array(12,21)

$filter->condition('category',$mix, 'IN');

But it is not working on search api query. Can anyone give me any alternate solution for this?

Thanks

Comment: What type of object is `$filter`? Because of the way SOLR's queries work, you'd probably be able to add multiple "category" conditions, each with a unique value, and they'd take effect

Comment: Let me paste little code here
$query = new SearchApiQuery($index);
$filter = $query->createFilter('AND');

Comment: What I understand I need to run foreach loop for multiple conditions?

foreach($term_name as $k=>$v){
     $category_filter->condition('category',$k);
      $query->filter($category_filter);
    //  $catTerms[$k] = $k;
    }

Like this?